# Secomea DCM 3529 multiple triggers or two values in the same reading

Tags: json, sensors, azure-iot-hub, data-collection, siemens

I am currently having troubles with Secomea Data Collection Module, I was wondering if anyone here might be able to enlighten me.
So I am collecting sensor data from the product **Secomea 3529** through a portal called Secomea Sitemanager. I can't seem to find any information about my two questions below, I hope someone knows the answer.

Information about protocol used in this project

```
"Protocol": "S7/TCP",
  "S7Access": {
    "S7Model": "S7-200",
    "S7Rack": 0,
    "S7Slot": 1
```

When collecting data it is programmed using JSON as seen below.

**I was wondering if it is possible to somehow have more than one TriggerSample and if so how is it set up?**

```
               {
      "SampleName": "Sensor1",
      "SampleDescription": "Some Description",
      "SampleDataType": "bool",
      "SamplesSaved": 3600,
      "Aggregation": {
        "Function": "compute",
        "Expression": "Sensor2,1,/",
        "TriggerSample": "Sensor3"
      }
    },
```

**My other question, is it possible to have more than one S7Var?**

```
       {
      "SampleName": "ModeCheck",
      "SampleDescription": "Mode status",
      "SampleDataType": "int16",
      "SamplesSaved": 360,
      "S7Var": {
        "S7PLCVar": "LocationInMachineDB1",
        "S7SampleInterval": 5
      } 
    },
```